# Nuxt.jsで画像読み込み時に404エラーが発生した際に代わりの画像に差し替えたい

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54596396/vue-js-nuxt-js-load-fallback-image-on-404

上記の記事を元に、以下のような「image1がエラーの時はimage2を表示する」というプログラムを作成しました。

しかし、imgタグ内が `src` であるときはうまく動作しますが、 `:src` とバインディングした際には 404発生時にも`@error` がトリガーされず困っています。
上記の方法以外でも目的が達成できれば良いので、実現方法があればご教授いただけると幸いです。

```
<img
 :src="image1"
 @error="setFallbackImageUrl"
>
```

```
methods: {
    setFallbackImageUrl(event) {
        event.target.src = 'image2'
    }
}
```

Comment: こちらも不可でしたhttps://qiita.com/dskymd/items/d538fbd8b0429d7a49ea

Answer (score 0):

試してみたところ、確かにページ表示直後はイベントが走りませんでした。
`image_path` という変数を `image[src=]` と `input[type=text]` の両方にバインドさせ、
入力値を変えるとイベントが発火しました。

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <input type="text," v-model="image_path">
      <img :src="image_path" @error="onError" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  asyncData () {
    return {
      image_path : "/testx.jpg" // 存在しないイメージ
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onError (e) {
    console.log(e)
    console.log(e.target)
      e.target.src = "https://sites.google.com/site/dekchysite95/_/rsrc/1480944463347/extra-credit/google.png"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

表示直後ではイベントが走らないのかもしれませんね。

ちなみに以下のコードだとページ表示直後に発火します。

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <input type="text," v-model="image_path">
      <img :src="image_path" @error="onError" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      image_path : ""
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onError (e) {
    console.log(e)
    console.log(e.target)
      e.target.src = "https://sites.google.com/site/dekchysite95/_/rsrc/1480944463347/extra-credit/google.png"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

`data()` 関数上は空にしておき、 `creatd()` 関数で値をセットする、という対処でどうでしょう？

Comment: ありがとうございます。いただいたコードはonErrorが発火したのですが、image_path:"test.png"のようにファイル名を入れるとこれも途端に動かなくなりました。。。拡張子がないなど明らかにエラーの場合しか発火しない様です。